# Override method with Generic param JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka

Following this tutorial: [LINK](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-custom-serializer)

I'm implementing the `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer` interface in this way:

```
public class CustomSerializer implements Serializer {
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public byte[] serialize(String s, OrderDto data) {
    try {
        if (data == null) {
            System.out.println("Null received at serializing");
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Serializing...");
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SerializationException("Error when serializing MessageDto to byte[]");
    }
}
```

But I'm obtaining this error:

```
Class 'CustomSerializer' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'serialize(String, T)' in 'Serializer'
```

If I override the serialize method in this way:

```
public byte[] serialize(String s, Object data) { ... }
```

Everything compile.

What I am missing ? OrderDto is an object too.

Comment: `implements Serializer` is a raw type. When you implement a generic interface, then also provide a generic type.

Comment: There's a bug in the tutorial (rare for Baeldung), it should implement `Serializer<OrderDto>`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning Kafka already has a builtin JSON Serializer for any type of object